# mongoose find from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hey I am quite new to mongoose and can't get my head around search.

***models***

```
User->resumes[]->employments[]
```

**UserSchema**

```js
{
    resumes: [ResumeSchema],
    ...
}
```

**ResumeSchema**

```js
{
    employments: [EmploymentSchema],
    ...
}
```

**EmploymentSchema**

```js
{
    jobTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Job title is required."]
    },
    ...
}
```

**Background**

User has to enter job title and needs suggestions from the existing data of the already present resumes and their employment's job title

I have tried the following code.

```js
let q = req.query.q; // Software
User.find({ "resumes.employments.jobTitle": new RegExp(req.query.q, 'ig') }, {
    "resumes.employments.$": 1
}, (err, docs) => {
    res.json(docs);
})
```

**Output**

```js
[
    {
        _id: '...',
        resumes:[
            {
                employments: [
                    {
                      jobTitle: 'Software Developer',
                      ...
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

**Expected OutPut**

```js
["Software Developer", "Software Engineer", "Software Manager"]
```

**Problem**
1:) The Data returned is too much as I only need jobTitle

2:) All employments are being returned whereas the query matched one of them

3:) Is there any better way to do it ? via index or via $search ? I did not find much of information in mongoose documentation to create search index (and I also don't really know how to create a compound index to make it work)

I know there might be a lot of answers but none of them helped or I was not able to make them work ... I am really new to mongodb I have been working with relational databases via SQL or through ORM so my mongodb concepts and knowledge is limited.

So please let me know if there is a better solution to do it. or something to make the current one working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the aggregation query below to get this result:

```
[
  {
    "jobTitle": [
      "Software Engineer",
      "Software Manager",
      "Software Developer"
    ]
  }
]
```

Query is:

- First using `$unwind` twice to deconstructs the arrays and get the values.
- Then `$match` to filter by values you want using `$regex`.
- Then `$group` to get all values together (using `_id: null` and `$addToSet` to no add duplicates).
- And finally `$project` to shown only the field you want.

```
User.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$resumes"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$resumes.employments"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "resumes.employments.jobTitle": {
      "$regex": "software",
      "$options": "i"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "jobTitle": {
      "$addToSet": "$resumes.employments.jobTitle"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pjknPbxKj5H)

Also another option is using `$filter` into `$project` stage:

Is similar as before but using `$filter` instead of `$unwind` twice.

```
User.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$resumes"
},
{
  "$project": {
    "jobs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$resumes.employments",
        "as": "e",
        "cond": {
          "$regexMatch": {
            "input": "$$e.jobTitle",
            "regex": "Software",
            "options": "i"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$jobs"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "jobTitle": {
      "$addToSet": "$jobs.jobTitle"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dAyJm6P1baR)

Comment: Got it working .. thank you.. just one thing .. The mongoose version I am using was expecting the aggregation pipelines in array of objects not as parameters ...

Comment: and thank you very much for detailed explanation ... that really makes a lot of sense now ..